# Setting date format in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to set format like this: `7 Aug 2015 14:42:11`

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Current :- %@",string);
```

Comment: try this formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";   @Ammy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `7 Aug 2015 14:42:11`, if you use this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Current :- %@",string);
```

Your mistake is incorrect date format,

`@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` should be this: `@"dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: can you explain your date format is correct or it is related to question

Comment: your answer is wrong , please customize your answer on  right way

Comment: it not small mistake in Dateformat is not in equal it showing NULL, so care the answer it is useful for future also , k Have the nice day and do good

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString myString = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";     
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMM, YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *string = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Current :- %@",string);

//Date Current :- 7 Aug, 2015 16:29:48
```

the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this method to your utility class and pass the date whatever you want to convert

+(NSString *)dateToString:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    return [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```